# Why (?<!index)\.html? can't match 'abc.html'

Tags: python, regex

```
m = re.match('(?<!index)\.html?', 'abc.html')
print(m)
```

can't match, on my memory it should work...
i'm a rookie,please help me. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.match` includes an implicit start of string anchor. The `(?<!index)` says the `.` can't be preceded by `index`, but it doesn't match anything that isn't `index` either, so the implicit anchor means that this effectively matches only strings that begin `.html?`.

To fix, either use `re.search` instead of `re.match` (removing the implicit anchor), or capture the preceding text explicitly (with the negative lookbehind assertion still excluding anything that ends with `index`):

```
m = re.match('.*(?<!index)\.html?', 'abc.html')  # Use re.fullmatch to prevent arbitrary suffixes
#             ^^ added
```

To allow things that end with `index`, but aren't exactly `index`, you can use an alternation:

```
m = re.match('(?:.{6,}|.{,5}(?<!index))\.html?', 'aindex.html')
```

where we allow a match if the name is at least six characters *or* it's five or less and they're not `index`.

I'll note, the complexity here means I'd be inclined to skip the regex entirely; plain string methods are going to be pretty good. For example, assuming this is just testing, not using the resulting match object, you could replace:

```
if re.match('(?:.{6,}|.{,5}(?<!index))\.html?', filename):
```

with either:

```
if filename.endswith(('.htm', '.html')) and filename not in ('index.htm', 'index.html'):
```

or:

```
root, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
if ext in ('.htm', '.html') and root != 'index':
```

Sure it's slightly longer, but it's far less complicated/error-prone.